# creating a file from two other files

Tags: c#, text, streamwriter, compareto

I have such code so far:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visible = true;
    label2.Visible = true;
    var items = File.ReadAllLines("updated database folder/Resellers_Inventory.txt").
    Skip(1).
    Select(s =>
    {
        var strings = s.Split('|');
        if (strings.Length != 2) throw new FormatException();
        return new { Code = strings[0], Stock = Convert.ToInt32(strings[1]) };
    }).
    ToArray();

    var compareTo = File.ReadAllLines("old database folder/ProductAll.txt").
                Skip(1).
                Select(s =>
                {
                    var strings = s.Split(',');
                    if (strings.Length != 6) throw new FormatException();
                    return new { Path = strings[2].Trim('"'), Id = Convert.ToInt32(strings[3]), Name = strings[4].Trim('"'), Code = strings[5].Trim('"'), Stock = Convert.ToInt32(strings[6]) };
                }).
                ToArray();

    string foldername = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy--MM--dd");
    Directory.CreateDirectory("Update file of " + foldername);
    string UpdeitoFailas = @"Update file of " + foldername + "/update.txt";

    foreach (var item in items.Where(i => compareTo.Any(i2 => i.Code == i2.Code)))
    {
        if ((File.Exists(UpdeitoFailas)) && i.Stock != i2.Stock)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(UpdeitoFailas))
            {
                sw.Write("Product, " + i2.Path + ", " + i2.Id + ", " + i2.Name + ", " + i2.Code + ", " + i.Stock);
             }
         }
     }
```

The file "Resellers_Inventory.txt" is like this (and consists hundreds of thousands lines):

```
Order Code|Stock
ACREPAIR|1031
AF813|18
AF823|12
AFCOB11|21
AFCS300|33
AFCS3000|1
AFEM4|5
AFOMNI|17
AFOX2|-3
AFOX3|-3
AFROD|28
AFSENSOR|50
AFUF21|24
AN00001|-1
AN00002|21
AN00003|4
AN00004|4
AN00005|9
...
```

ProductAll.txt file also consists hundreds of thousands lines which looks like these:

```
Action,CategoryPath,ID,Name,Code,Stock
"Product","Home > Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED, Multicolour",2226,"KINGBRIGHT LED, 3MM, HE-RED/GRN L-93WEGW","SC07621",202
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2228,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 10K0 CRCW040210K0JNEAIF","RE06211",0
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2229,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 3R90 CRCW04023R90JNEAIF","RE06212",0
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2230,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 2R70 CRCW04022R70JNEAIF","RE06220",25
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2231,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 33R0 CRCW040233R0JNEAIF","RE06221",0
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2232,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 100R CRCW0402100RJNEAIF","RE06226",0
"Product","Home > IC's > Comparators",2234,"STMICROELECTRONICS IC, COMPARATOR DUAL, DIP8, 393 LM393N","SC10207",57
"Product","Home > IC's > Amplifiers > Operational",2237,"STMICROELECTRONICS OP AMP, QUAD JFET, DIP14 TL084CN","SC07929",82
"Product","Home > IC's > Amplifiers > Audio Power",2239,"NATIONAL SEMICONDUCTOR AMP, AUDIO 0.25W, DIP8, 386 LM386N-1","SC08430",83
"Product","Home > IC's > Microcontrollers",2241,"MICROCHIP 8BIT FLASH MCU, 12F675, DIP8 PIC12F675-I/P","ACREPAIR",16
...
```

Basically what I want to do is to create third file which would look like ProductAll.txt, but would be different in such way: if in Resellers_Inventory.txt stock is different from ProductAll.txt then we write a line to update.txt which looks same as line in ProductAll.txt but with stock value from Resellers_Inventory.txt. If stock values are same we skip this line and don't write to our new third file. Matching lines (stocks) is implemented by matching item codes which are same in both files.

At the moment I'm getting such errors:

```
Error   1   The name 'i' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 90  53  WindowsFormsApplication1
Error   2   The name 'i2' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 90  64  WindowsFormsApplication1
Error   3   The name 'i2' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 94  48  WindowsFormsApplication1
Error   4   The name 'i2' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 94  65  WindowsFormsApplication1
Error   5   The name 'i2' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 94  80  WindowsFormsApplication1
Error   6   The name 'i2' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 94  97  WindowsFormsApplication1
Error   7   The name 'i' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\Tutis\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 94  114 WindowsFormsApplication1
```

But even without this I don't know how to write to new update.txt file symbols **"** that lines would look same as in ProductAll.txt just with other stock value.

Comment: You use the variables of the lambda expressions... They are out of scope where you use them.

Comment: Can you suggest what should I change to reach the goal?

Comment: You could look up what I mean by my comment. I have the feeling you didn't really understand the "out of scope" part. (I don't mean it in a demeaning way.)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit hard to see whats going on in the code, but you can use `File.WriteAllLines` to create your results file.

I'm using my answer from your question yesterday to show it working as i can't get the example you posted working.

```
    private void UpdateProducts()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            List<string> updatedProducts = new List<string>();
            List<string[]> stock = new List<string[]>(File.ReadAllLines("G:\\Stock.txt").Select(line => line.Split('|')));
            List<string> products = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("G:\\Products.txt"));
            updatedProducts.Add(products[0]);
            SetProgress(products.Count);
            foreach (var item in products)
            {
                if (stock.Any(s => item.Contains(s[0]) && !item.EndsWith(s[1])))
                {
                    string[] p = item.Split(',');
                    int productStockIndex = Array.IndexOf(p, p.Last());
                    int productNameIndex = productStockIndex - 1;
                    string productName = p[productNameIndex].Replace("\"", "");
                    p[productStockIndex] = stock.First(stk => stk[0] == productName)[1];
                    updatedProducts.Add(string.Join(",", p));
                }
                UpdateProgress(updatedProducts.Count);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(@"G:\Results.txt", updatedProducts.ToArray());
        });
    }

    private void SetProgress(int maxValue)
    {
        base.Invoke((Action)delegate 
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = maxValue;
        });
    }

    private void UpdateProgress(int value)
    {
        base.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            progressBar1.Value = value;
        });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateProducts();
    }
```

good luck :)

Comment: Im trying your method, but Im getting couple errors: `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 111 13 WindowsFormsApplication1
Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]' Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 111 51 WindowsFormsApplication1`
Which are found in File.WriteAllLines line

Comment: Are you using the whole method I posted or just the File.WriteAllLines part? as this method works fine for the 2 text examples you posted

Comment: Ahh.. must be a different .NET version, I added `ToArray()` this should make it work, .Net4.0 accepts `IEnumerable<string>` as a param for `WriteAllLines`, .NET3.0 does not

Comment: Now compiles without problems, but when testing program goes to "Not respoinding" state, probably because there are hundred thousands lines (I tried with ten thousands but was same) and Im using netbook at the moment which is not the beast to process such things...

Comment: Yeah, you may want to start this on another thread, I updated answear, but with 10,000's of lines this will take some time.

Comment: If your doing 100,000's of lines you may want to break this into groups to save memory/performance issues

Comment: Just realized you only want the changed items to be part of the new file, I have updated answer to do this

Comment: Now it's not crashing, but after 20 mins I'm still waiting for results file :) But it seems that it will work, is it posible with this method to count the update lines (changed stocks), couse I would like them to be displayed in form it wouldnt look so static as user would wate for result.

Comment: I added logic for a ProgressBar, However I don't think this is a good solution for 100,000's of lines as this will be a memory hog

Comment: I havethe to say, that it crashed after some time (without progress bar addition), suggesting to debug the program in visual studio but debuging also crashed. Now trying in beast laptop for results

Comment: Worked in better laptop :) Will tell more details after work, Im very thankful for your help and time sa_ddam

Comment: sa_damm213, how could I before adding all lines to new file add first line "Action,CategoryPath,ID,Name,Code,Stock" ?

Comment: In my work computer debuged app worked fine (laptop 64 bit architecture, beasty parameters) but my home netbook and girlfriends laptop (which is kinda normal) after starting update proces after some time crashes (program stopped working...). Why could it be? Because of huge sizes of files (but I think it wouldnt crash, only would take more time to process) or could be the reason, that update file has lines with some codes which dont exist in second file, m?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it will not work with the data you have in "ProductAll.txt"

You need to split the lines in the CSV having comma as the delimiter, but **KEEP** the commas between double quotes.

String.Split() is not  a good choice for that job. Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, you can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) free library for reading CSV Files.

The only thing you need to do to use it, is to add a reference to the LumenWorks.Framework.IO.dll

Here is a sample console project that does what you want using the "**Fast CSV Reader**" library and a **dictionary** to speed up the lookups you do on the *Code* field.

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestProgram
{
    class Product
    {
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string CategoryPath { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static string DoubleQuoteString(this string str)
        {
            return '"' + str + '"';
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var resellersInventoryQuery = from lineTokens in ReadCsvLines("data\\Resellers_Inventory.txt", true, '|')
                                          select new { Code = lineTokens[0], Stock = Convert.ToInt32(lineTokens[1]) };

            Dictionary<string, int> orderStock = resellersInventoryQuery.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Code, kvp => kvp.Stock);

            var allProductsQuery = from lineTokens in ReadCsvLines("data\\ProductAll.txt", true, ',')
                                   let product = ParseProduct(lineTokens)
                                   select product;

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("data\\updated.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var product in allProductsQuery)
                {
                    if (orderStock.ContainsKey(product.Code))
                    {
                        int newStockValue = orderStock[product.Code];
                        if (newStockValue != product.Stock)
                        {
                            product.Stock = orderStock[product.Code];
                            sw.WriteLine(ToString(product));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsvLines(string file, bool hasHeader, char delimiter)
        {
            using (CsvReader csr = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file), hasHeader, delimiter))
            {
                int fieldCount = csr.FieldCount;
                while (csr.ReadNextRecord())
                {
                    List<string> lineTokens = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                        lineTokens.Add(csr[i]);
                    yield return lineTokens.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        static Product ParseProduct(string[] tokens)
        {
            Product product = new Product();

            product.Action = tokens[0];
            product.CategoryPath = tokens[1];
            product.ID = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[2]);
            product.Name = tokens[3];
            product.Code = tokens[4];
            product.Stock = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[5]);

            return product;
        }

        static string ToString(Product product)
        {
            const char SEPERATOR = ',';

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(product.Action.DoubleQuoteString()); sb.Append(SEPERATOR);
            sb.Append(product.CategoryPath.DoubleQuoteString()); sb.Append(SEPERATOR);
            sb.Append(product.ID); sb.Append(SEPERATOR);
            sb.Append(product.Name.DoubleQuoteString()); sb.Append(SEPERATOR);
            sb.Append(product.Code.DoubleQuoteString()); sb.Append(SEPERATOR);
            sb.Append(product.Stock);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You can put the classes to different files according to your needs. E.g. move the Product class to its own file. And of course add some error handling.

Hope this helps.